# Owl Carousel AutoPlayTimeout Does Not Scroll Smoothly

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm having a bit of an issue getting the autoplayTimeout to scroll smoothly on the page.  It stops after it loads the first 5 images and scrolls the next one in and it is very jerky.  You can see an example [here at the bottom of the page](http://isouldesigns.com/neracs) .

Here are my settings within the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
                autoplay: true,     
                items: 5,
                autoplayHoverPause: true,
                autoplayTimeout: 10,
                autoplaySpeed: 1000,
                fluidSpeed:true,
                itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
                itemsDesktopSmall: [979,3],
                itemsMobile: [479,1],
                navigation: false,
                dots: false,
                loop: true
                });

        });

    </script>
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the right combination of settings.

Comment: Hey Nina,
I've facing the same issue and I need what you have on the link you posted on your question.
Would you please give me information about how you accomplished that?
Your help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
jQuery('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            items:3,
            autoplay: true,
            slideTransition: 'linear',
            autoplayTimeout: 6000,
            autoplaySpeed: 6000,
        });
```

I'm using this code for my own carousel to make carousel smooth. Note: you have to define both autoplayTimeout and autoplaySpeed value should be same otherwise it will jerk when first slide is coming from the last slide.

Answer (score 4):

**Using smartSpeed property :**

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({ autoplay: true, smartSpeed: 2500 });
```